# ##[error]ERROR: GC overhead limit exceeded - SonarQube in TFS Build

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops, tfsbuild, sonarqube-scan

We are running SonarQube from TFS CI task.

Before some time SonarQube analysis was getting success when I trigger build manually but the same build is giving an error and now this is not working from my user with manual trigger also.

> [error]ERROR: GC overhead limit exceeded

While Auto trigger as we have configured **Nightly scheduled build** with the different TFS user.

This is how I configured System variable for `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS` which is working fine with manual trigger

[image: X]

I have checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=vsts#default-permissions-assigned-to-built-in-security-groups) document as it seems user permission issue.

User Permissions:

[image: X]

And, according to this TFS User have this access of Build Administrator and Project Administrator to access Variable `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS` I've defined.

Comment: Passing SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS in the properties field will not work. You have to define it as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a variable in the VSTS build called `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS` with a value of `-Xmx8192m`, then try it again.

See Dinesh's comments in this similar issue: [GC overhead limit exceeded using the VSTS task](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-using-the-vsts-task/2528)

> Try to give more memory to the `Run Code Analysis` task rather than
>   the `Prepare analysis on SonarQube` task.
>
> Also both `sonar.web.javaOpts` and `sonar.ce.javaOpts` are server-side
>   options for SonarQube operation. You do not need to worry about those
>   as you are relying on SonarCloud. Setting those for an analysis during
>   a build will have no effect. Just set `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS` which as you
>   saw in your deleted post does have an effect (i.e. setting it to 4096
>   bytes did lead to an immediate failure of the JVM)

Comment: Hey @Andy, We have TFS on the premises.

Comment: @DarshanaPatel TFS and VSTS have the same build system, that's also available for on-premise TFS, just have a try for that.